# Limit of a function using the calculator

Tags: calculus, limits

The problem is: find $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\tan(x) - x}{x^3}$ using the calculator.

I know that the limit should be $\frac{1}{3}$, but what I get plugging in very small numbers is $0$.
Now, I know that the function is oscillating very fast about the origin, but still I was expecting to find good approximations of 0.33333 taking smaller and smaller $x$...I was expecting this since this reflects my idea of limit...

Could you explain me what is going on?

Comment: What kind of calculator do you used? I used a TI-Nspire and when I plugged $0,01$ I got $0,333346...$.

Comment: keep adding zeros...

Comment: Using $0.01$, $0.001$ (and of course radian mode) I get about the right thing with my cheap calculator. With $0.0000001$ I get $0$. The reason is simple: the calculator computes internally to about $12$ decimal places. For very small $x$, $\tan x-x$ is, from the calculator's point of view, equal to $0$.  Fix: Use fancy stuff (Wolfram Alpha) or confine yourself to numbers that are small but not **too** small.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are suffering from [loss of significance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_of_significance).  You are considering that $\tan (x) \approx x + \frac {x^3}3$ for $x \ll 1$  which is correct.  Your calculator stores numbers with (say) $10$ decimal places.  If you ask for $\tan(10^{-10})-10^{-10}$  it will calculate each term to $10$ place accuracy, but they are equal.   $\frac {x^3}3=\frac 13\cdot 10^{-30}$ so the calculator doesn't know about it.  The numerator is then zero and you get zero.  As noted in the comments, if you take $x$ somewhat larger, like $0.1$ or $0.001$ you will get something close to $\frac 13$

Comment: That makes sense! Thank you!!! :)

Comment: A large part of numerical analysis is avoiding loss of significance.  It often comes from subtracting two numbers that differ by much less than the numbers themselves, as here.  It has become less of an issue as computers carry more precision, but it can still bite you.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there is no oscillation near the origin (things like $\sin(1/x)$, e.g. will oscillate rapidly near the origin, but $\lim_{x\to 0} \tan(x) = 0$ is pretty straightforward).

<strike>I would check carefully the expression you have entered in the calculator. For instance, if you accidentally entered something like</strike>

> `tan(x - x)/x^3`

etc.

Other answers have suggested a more fitting culprit for this problem, but I'll stand by my claim that the function does not oscillate near the origin.

Comment: http://www.slader.com/textbook/9780538497909-stewart-calculus-early-transcendentals-7th-edition/98/exercises/44d/

not so straighforward, isn't it?

Comment: Those are numerical precision issues; the actual function **does not** oscillate like that. Look at a graph of the derivative, it's positive for $x$ near $0$.

Comment: you are right, thank you for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0):

Your idea of a limit is perfecly right, but the calculation of tan(x)-x for very small
 x is numerically instable (You subtract two nearly equal numbers).

This is the reason, that you got 0. In theory, the approximation gets better and
 better.